# Virtual Machine Snapshots

Tags: virtual-machine, snapshot, vsphere

I am taking a snapshot of a virtual machine using VSphere. My problem is that it is taking a very long time and I have some things I need to do on that virtual machine. My question is: Is it safe for me to use the VM while the snapshot is being created? Why or why not?

("Safe" as in will the snapshot be ruined? Will the snapshot be taken at some intermediate state instead of the time that I originally initiated the snapshot?)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a snapshot is usually a fast operation where writes are redirected to other files (in order to revert them). If the operation takes a long time it might be caused of including saving the vm:s memory to disk as well. If this is not the case maybe you have an issue where taking the snapshot isn't working.

Under normal situations there shouldn't be any problem working of changing data inside the vm at this point.